# Why am I getting OAuth errors when using the SoundCloud API?

Tags: iphone, soundcloud

I have created an iPhone test application. Also I have integrated SoundCloud with the test application.

Also I got consumer key and consumer secret. When I tried to run my application, I am getting following messages.

```
2010-11-03 15:49:11.420 iPhoneTestApp[883:207] No CallbackURL supplied
2010-11-03 15:49:11.510 iPhoneTestApp[883:207] OAuth is not initialized with all 3 URLs
2010-11-03 15:49:11.511 iPhoneTestApp[883:207] OAuth is not initialized with all 3 URLs
2010-11-03 15:49:11.512 iPhoneTestApp[883:207] API is not configured with base URL
```

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved it.

Again I registered with SoundCloud.com. I got the consumer key and consumer secret, I have used that key in my application. Then it is working fine.